# Don't get connected to firebase after updating

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've updated my android studio 
This is my build gradle:

```
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`
```

the difference between design and appcombat are no problem.
This is my logcat when i start my app:

> 10-24 14:05:12.428 2729-2765/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module
>   descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. 10-24
>   14:05:12.530 2729-2781/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   11020000 but found 10932470 10-24 14:05:12.625
>   2729-2765/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe W/GooglePlayServicesUtil:
>   Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found
>   10932470 10-24 14:05:12.873 2729-2743/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe
>   I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 6986(2MB) AllocSpace
>   objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 62% free, 903KB/2MB, paused 439us total
>   190.297ms 10-24 14:05:13.073 2729-2781/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used 10-24
>   14:05:13.076 2729-2781/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe D/FA: Logging
>   event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Login,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=4467516799880805849}] 10-24 14:05:13.142
>   2729-2800/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL
>   Pipeline 10-24 14:05:13.163 2729-2729/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe
>   W/FA: Service connection failed:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,
>   resolution=null, message=null} 10-24 14:05:13.236
>   2729-2781/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe W/GooglePlayServicesUtil:
>   Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found
>   10932470 10-24 14:05:13.260 2729-2781/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe
>   E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send app launch 10-24 14:05:13.260
>   2729-2781/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe E/FA: Failed to get app
>   instance id 10-24 14:05:13.262
>   2729-2781/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe E/FA: Failed to send current
>   screen to service 10-24 14:05:13.262
>   2729-2781/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe E/FA: Discarding data.
>   Failed to send event to service 10-24 14:05:13.476
>   2729-2800/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe I/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Initialized EGL, version 1.4 10-24 14:05:13.476
>   2729-2800/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap
>   behavior 1 10-24 14:05:13.477
>   2729-2800/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to
>   choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>   10-24 14:05:13.818 2729-2729/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe W/FA:
>   Service connection failed:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,
>   resolution=null, message=null}

Comment: Try re sync your client with your Firebase app, and add again the .json file. In android studio 2.3 just click on tools>firebase and in the assistant check if your app is connected to.

Comment: i've checked this out, it is connected. This doesn't solve my problem. 
but thanks

Comment: are you sure that you have enabled that auth method in the Firebase console?

Comment: All the Android Support libraries should use the same version. Update the design support dependency to version 26 and also post your project level gradle

Comment: the difference is not the problem, before the update it works very fie with this. my project level is  : 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

Comment: @AvinashRoy yes i'm sure. everything works before the update. i changed nothing and after the update nothing works

Comment: are u running on the emulator or ur own device?

Comment: running on the emulator all the time 
i also tried different emulator

Comment: downgrade ur firebase library and u will definitely connect this time

Comment: google service plugin 3.1.0..???

Comment: i tried but still had the problem

Comment: i fixed my problem, i downgraded also the google play services, now it works fine.
thank you all for your help

Comment: Instead of downgrading you should upgrade each dependency and and also build version. Though if your problem is solved add an answer that might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by downgrading all my dependencies

maybe it just solved my probem because downgrading is not the best way, but in my case it was the only thing that solved. I upgraded everything and then my problem comes.

Comment: If you are using emulator, you should create a new one with the latest API version

Answer (score 0):

When i faced the issue my dependencies was below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Then i decreased the version of dependencies like 10.0.1 and solved the issues:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

If it not works then, **clean project** and **rebuild project** and then run again

Comment: thanks, but i solved my problem by myself as i wrote above